# Laravel 5.8 async queue issue using supervisor

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord, laravel-5.8, laravel-queue

I am using Laravel queues in my application, I have following configuration,

**.env**:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
SESSION_DRIVER=file
```

**config/queue.config**

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync'),


'connections' => [

    'sync' => [
        'driver' => 'sync',
    ],

    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ]
]
```

I have setup `supervisor` and it has following configuration

**/etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel_queue.sh**

```
[program:laravel_queue]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /usr/local/bin/run_queue.sh
startsecs = 0
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
redirect_stderr=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/laraqueue.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/laraqueue.out.log
```

**/usr/local/bin/run_queue.sh**

```
php /var/www/myproject/artisan queue:work --tries=1
```

**Problem:**

When I set `QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync` it works fine, but jobs are executed synchronously. I want them to execute asynchronously. So when I set `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database` my jobs are not executed at all and I can see them sitting in my `jobs` table.

I have also observed that when I run `php artisan queue:work` directly from my project's directory it works as expected, that is jobs are executed asynchronously.

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Comment: What is `/usr/local/bin/run_queue.sh`?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Queue section of the Laravel docs (5.4)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#supervisor-configuration):

> ## Configuring Supervisor
>
> Supervisor configuration files are typically stored in the
>   `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` directory. Within this directory, you may
>   create any number of configuration files that instruct supervisor how
>   your processes should be monitored. For example, let's create a
>   `laravel-worker.conf` file that starts and monitors a `queue:work`
>   process:
>
> ```
> [program:laravel-worker]
> process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
> command=php /home/forge/app.com/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3
> autostart=true
> autorestart=true
> user=forge
> numprocs=8
> redirect_stderr=true
> stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/worker.log
> ```
>
> In this example, the `numprocs` directive will instruct Supervisor to
>   run 8 `queue:work` processes and monitor all of them, automatically
>   restarting them if they fail. Of course, you should change the
>   `queue:work sqs` portion of the `command` directive to reflect your
>   desired queue connection.
>
> ### Starting Supervisor
>
> Once the configuration file has been created, you may update the
>   Supervisor configuration and start the processes using the following
>   commands:
>
> ```
> sudo supervisorctl reread
>
> sudo supervisorctl update
>
> sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*
> ```
>
> For more information on Supervisor, consult the Supervisor
>   [documentation](http://supervisord.org/index.html).

A brief explanation about this commands ([source](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/720#issuecomment-359222022)):

> - **reread** - Reread supervisor configuration. Do not update or restart the running services.
> - **update** - Restart service(s) whose configuration has changed. Usually run after 'reread'.
> - **reload** - Reread supervisor configuration, reload supervisord and supervisorctl, restart services that were started.
> - **restart** - Restart service(s)

As an addition, [this article](http://www.onurguzel.com/supervisord-restarting-and-reloading/) can throw some lights to your issue. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the Laravel 5.8 but I set up the followings for Laravel 5.3

```
// Define the queue driver
php /var/www/myproject/artisan queue:work database --tries=1
```

and defined the `numprocs=1` in the supervisord configuration file.